# Entity Framework Filtering with a List of String

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to filter results According to List of strings, something like this:

```
List<string> filters = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
var results = (from R in db.Entries 
               where R.word.StartsWith(filters[0])
               ||R.word.StartsWith(filters[1])
               ||R.word.StartsWith(filters[2])
               ||...
```

I don't know the Length of my filters List so how to Query it dynamically in LINQ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yup, they are single letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works a little bit different in Linq, kind of the other way around

Use the .Contains()

Something like this:

```
from r in db.entries
where filters.contains (r.word.substring(0,1))
```

Comment: this works great!, but I'm wondering does calling substring(0,1) for every word in database costs much time?
I think I will have a performance issue (Entries table contains more than 100k words)

Comment: You can check the gernerated SQL in Linq to sql

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
var results = db.Entries 
    .Where(r => filters.Any(f => r.word.StartsWith(f)));
```

Extension method [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) is a way to "fold" a chain of ORs `||` applied to a list into a single call.

Comment: You could also replace Any with All. Any behave like OR and All more like AND.